# Can't fetch data from MySQL with almost same name in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted 3 rows to my DB table `orders`.

One of the columns that I fetch data from is `barname_num`.

The 3 rows have these values for the mentioned col :

```
hdm1350WIRG6351-01

hdm1350WIRG6351-02

hdm1350WIRG6351-03
```

The problem is that none of these are fetched ! I'm using `mysqli_fetch_array` and I tried `mysqli_fetch_assoc` but still not working.

All other rows are fine and the problem is only with these 3 rows ! What is the problem ?!

Update* : I tried to change `Collation` but it is not relevant.

Here is the php code by the way :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE barname_num = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $sql)){
    echo "sql not prepared!";
    exit();
}
else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , "s" , $barname_num);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is the value of `$barname_num`?

Comment: I have mentioned the values

Comment: Those are the values in the table, what is the value of the variable that you're using in the PHP code?

Comment: They are the same in this case

Comment: A variable can't have 3 values.

Comment: It is fetched from $_GET and it is fetched correctly

Comment: If it were really correct, you would get a result when you fetch.

Comment: Man don't you get it ! I'm saying it is fetched from $_GET !

Comment: I know how you get it, but why won't you tell me what the actual value is? What does `var_dump($barname_num);` show?

Comment: string(18) "hdm1350WIRG6351-01"

Comment: string(18) "hdm1350WIRG6351-02"

Comment: string(18) "hdm1350WIRG6351-03"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240446/discussion-between-barmar-and-jack-forest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there may be some invisible characters in the data. As a workaround until you can straighten that out, you can use `LIKE` to ignore them.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE barname_num LIKE ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
$barname_num = "%$barname_num%";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , "s" , $barname_num);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
if($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: I will test it in a new whole project and let you know. thanks again

Comment: I tested it and found out that the problem was in fact a TAB in the database values. How ever, why it is generated automatically, I don't know but that was where the problem came from.

Comment: This forces me to say this to everyone. Always trim() your data :)

Comment: Indeed, I have answered many questions in practically every language with `trim()` or the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

remove white space from value and try or You can use  `LIKE` .

Comment: already answered . not needed